# Can sliding list hold categories and sub categories?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using ionic 3, I have categories, when you click on one, you go to a subcategory, when you click on one you go to a sub category, if it exists or to the chosen category.

I totally could make them 3 separate pages, but I wonder if that's the best idea. I found [list enableSlidingItems](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/list/List/) and I thought this is the best solution, I create all the categories in one page easily.

But when I try to implement it, all the docs look like this

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list show-delete="false" can-swipe="true">
    <ion-item-sliding>
      <ion-item>todo 1</ion-item>
      <ion-item-options side="right">
        <button color="danger" ion-button>
          <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
    <ion-item>todo 2</ion-item>
    <ion-item>todo 3</ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

This example has two problems, it seems that the sliding effect is only there to show hidden buttons, and secondly you don't transition to another list as shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2CENbY8AyWM).

Isn't there a better way to pick a category other than creating 3 different pages? I want to have this transition effect, you pick a category you to another list but I don't like to create a different page for it. For different reasons, firstly it's easier to manage on one page and secondly, if the admin added new sub sub menu, I'll have to create a new page to handle that.

The api looks something like this, I don't think creating a new page for every sub category array is the smartest solution but I can't find another.

```
{
    "category": [
        {
            "name": "Vehicles",
            "parent": 0,
            "sub": [
                {
                    "name": "All in Vehicles",
                    "slug": "vehicles",
                    "parent": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "Cars",
                    "parent": 2,
                    "sub": [
                        {
                            "name": "All in Cars",
                            "slug": "cars",
                            "parent": 3
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Alfa Romeo",
                            "slug": "alfa-romeo",
                            "parent": 4
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Aston Martin",
                            "slug": "aston-martin",
                            "parent": 4
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Motorcycles",
                    "parent": 2,
                    "sub": [
                        {
                            "name": "All in Motorcycles",
                            "slug": "motorcycles",
                            "parent": 3
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Harley Davidson",
                            "slug": "harley-davidson",
                            "parent": 4
                        }

                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Electronics",
            "parent": 0,
            "sub": [
                {
                    "name": "All in Electronics",
                    "slug": "electronics",
                    "parent": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "phones",
                    "parent": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: So how many tier1 categories (like vehicles) could be there? Sliding item is not for your use case, i think you could get away with some lists magic but i would want to learn more about expected json structure in order to help you

Comment: @SergeyRudenko https://jokerleb.com vehicles, proprieties etc are categories, in total 14 categories and I don't know how many sub categories and sub sub categories. For now there's at most 3 levels. The json file is written by hand coz the api does not return categories, the file is 1644 lines and 41kb big.

Comment: Got it, your data structure is a bit weird in json, specifically that you have “all vehicles” section its not clear why its designed this way

Comment: @SergeyRudenko the reason is, if the user clicks all vehicles, he should be able to see all vehicles (all cars, all motorcycles, all trucks) those are children of vehicles

Comment: Got it so you are trying to recreate something similar to jokerleb.com's "menu" navigation? tree like structure to end up at specific category/subcategory? Do you aim at mobile experience (smaller screen) or also want desktop pwa?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko I aim for a mobile experience, you click on a list, you go to the next list, and so on